# "No imaging component suitable to complete this operation was found."

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, exception

I have programmed an application that it needs to download *.png files and set it into the background of the button in `WPF`. So, when i run this program, it faces the Error as

> No imaging component suitable to complete this operation was found."

My code is as below :

First application downloads the file with `WebClient` class's object:

```
System.Net.WebClient wClient = new System.Net.WebClient();
Uri downloadUri = new Uri(MyUri, UriKind.Absolute);
wClient.DownloadFileAsync(downloadUri, "MyImage.png");
wClient.DownloadFileCompleted += new System.ComponentModel.AsyncCompletedEventHandler(wClient_DownloadFileCompleted);
```

and when download completed event occurred:

```
ImageBtn.Dispatcher.Invoke(new Action(() =>
{
    ImageBrush ib = new ImageBrush();
    BitmapImage bi = new BitmapImage();
    bi.BeginInit();
    bi.UriSource = new Uri("MyImage.png", UriKind.Relative);
    bi.EndInit();

    ib.ImageSource = bi;
    ImageBtn.Background = ib;
}
```

**NOTE**
Because of run these blocks of codes in `BackgroundWorker`, I use `Dispatcher` to set button `Background` property

So, when i run the program, `System.NotSupportedException` occurred as below :

> Exception from HRESULT: 0x88982F50 Error Code : -2003292336 Message :
>   No imaging component suitable to complete this operation was found.
>   Source : PresentationCore Stack Trace :    at
>   System.Windows.Media.Imaging.BitmapDecoder.SetupDecoderFromUriOrStream(Uri
>   uri, Stream stream, BitmapCacheOption cacheOption, Guid& clsId,
>   Boolean& isOriginalWritable, Stream& uriStream, UnmanagedMemoryStream&
>   unmanagedMemoryStream, SafeFileHandle& safeFilehandle)    at
>   System.Windows.Media.Imaging.BitmapDecoder.CreateFromUriOrStream(Uri
>   baseUri, Uri uri, Stream stream, BitmapCreateOptions createOptions,
>   BitmapCacheOption cacheOption, RequestCachePolicy uriCachePolicy,
>   Boolean insertInDecoderCache)    at
>   System.Windows.Media.Imaging.BitmapImage.FinalizeCreation()    at
>   System.Windows.Media.Imaging.BitmapSource.CompleteDelayedCreation()
>   at System.Windows.Media.Imaging.BitmapSource.get_WicSourceHandle()
>   at System.Windows.Media.Imaging.BitmapSource.get_DUCECompatiblePtr()
>   at
>   System.Windows.Media.Imaging.BitmapSource.UpdateBitmapSourceResource(Channel
>   channel, Boolean skipOnChannelCheck)    at
>   System.Windows.Media.Imaging.BitmapSource.AddRefOnChannelCore(Channel
>   channel)    at
>   System.Windows.Media.Imaging.BitmapSource.System.Windows.Media.Composition.DUCE.IResource.AddRefOnChannel(Channel
>   channel)    at
>   System.Windows.Media.ImageBrush.AddRefOnChannelCore(Channel channel)
>   at
>   System.Windows.Media.Brush.System.Windows.Media.Composition.DUCE.IResource.AddRefOnChannel(Channel
>   channel)    at
>   System.Windows.Media.RenderData.System.Windows.Media.Composition.DUCE.IResource.AddRefOnChannel(Channel
>   channel)    at System.Windows.UIElement.RenderContent(RenderContext
>   ctx, Boolean isOnChannel)    at
>   System.Windows.Media.Visual.UpdateContent(RenderContext ctx,
>   VisualProxyFlags flags, Boolean isOnChannel)    at
>   System.Windows.Media.Visual.RenderRecursive(RenderContext ctx)    at
>   System.Windows.Media.Visual.UpdateChildren(RenderContext ctx,
>   ResourceHandle handle)    at
>   System.Windows.Media.Visual.RenderRecursive(RenderContext ctx)    at
>   System.Windows.Media.Visual.UpdateChildren(RenderContext ctx,
>   ResourceHandle handle)    at
>   System.Windows.Media.Visual.RenderRecursive(RenderContext ctx)    at
>   System.Windows.Media.Visual.UpdateChildren(RenderContext ctx,
>   ResourceHandle handle)    at
>   System.Windows.Media.Visual.RenderRecursive(RenderContext ctx)    at
>   System.Windows.Media.Visual.UpdateChildren(RenderContext ctx,
>   ResourceHandle handle)    at
>   System.Windows.Media.Visual.RenderRecursive(RenderContext ctx)    at
>   System.Windows.Media.Visual.UpdateChildren(RenderContext ctx,
>   ResourceHandle handle)    at
>   System.Windows.Media.Visual.RenderRecursive(RenderContext ctx)    at
>   System.Windows.Media.Visual.UpdateChildren(RenderContext ctx,
>   ResourceHandle handle)    at
>   System.Windows.Media.Visual.RenderRecursive(RenderContext ctx)    at
>   System.Windows.Media.Visual.UpdateChildren(RenderContext ctx,
>   ResourceHandle handle)    at
>   System.Windows.Media.Visual.RenderRecursive(RenderContext ctx)    at
>   System.Windows.Media.Visual.UpdateChildren(RenderContext ctx,
>   ResourceHandle handle)    at
>   System.Windows.Media.Visual.RenderRecursive(RenderContext ctx)    at
>   System.Windows.Media.Visual.UpdateChildren(RenderContext ctx,
>   ResourceHandle handle)    at
>   System.Windows.Media.Visual.RenderRecursive(RenderContext ctx)    at
>   System.Windows.Media.Visual.UpdateChildren(RenderContext ctx,
>   ResourceHandle handle)    at
>   System.Windows.Media.Visual.RenderRecursive(RenderContext ctx)    at
>   System.Windows.Media.Visual.UpdateChildren(RenderContext ctx,
>   ResourceHandle handle)    at
>   System.Windows.Media.Visual.RenderRecursive(RenderContext ctx)    at
>   System.Windows.Media.Visual.UpdateChildren(RenderContext ctx,
>   ResourceHandle handle)    at
>   System.Windows.Media.Visual.RenderRecursive(RenderContext ctx)    at
>   System.Windows.Media.Visual.UpdateChildren(RenderContext ctx,
>   ResourceHandle handle)    at
>   System.Windows.Media.Visual.RenderRecursive(RenderContext ctx)    at
>   System.Windows.Media.Visual.UpdateChildren(RenderContext ctx,
>   ResourceHandle handle)    at
>   System.Windows.Media.Visual.RenderRecursive(RenderContext ctx)    at
>   System.Windows.Media.Visual.UpdateChildren(RenderContext ctx,
>   ResourceHandle handle)    at
>   System.Windows.Media.Visual.RenderRecursive(RenderContext ctx)    at
>   System.Windows.Media.Visual.UpdateChildren(RenderContext ctx,
>   ResourceHandle handle)    at
>   System.Windows.Media.Visual.RenderRecursive(RenderContext ctx)    at
>   System.Windows.Media.Visual.UpdateChildren(RenderContext ctx,
>   ResourceHandle handle)    at
>   System.Windows.Media.Visual.RenderRecursive(RenderContext ctx)    at
>   System.Windows.Media.Visual.UpdateChildren(RenderContext ctx,
>   ResourceHandle handle)    at
>   System.Windows.Media.Visual.RenderRecursive(RenderContext ctx)    at
>   System.Windows.Media.Visual.UpdateChildren(RenderContext ctx,
>   ResourceHandle handle)    at
>   System.Windows.Media.Visual.RenderRecursive(RenderContext ctx)    at
>   System.Windows.Media.Visual.UpdateChildren(RenderContext ctx,
>   ResourceHandle handle)    at
>   System.Windows.Media.Visual.RenderRecursive(RenderContext ctx)    at
>   System.Windows.Media.Visual.UpdateChildren(RenderContext ctx,
>   ResourceHandle handle)    at
>   System.Windows.Media.Visual.RenderRecursive(RenderContext ctx)    at
>   System.Windows.Media.Visual.UpdateChildren(RenderContext ctx,
>   ResourceHandle handle)    at
>   System.Windows.Media.Visual.RenderRecursive(RenderContext ctx)    at
>   System.Windows.Media.Visual.UpdateChildren(RenderContext ctx,
>   ResourceHandle handle)    at
>   System.Windows.Media.Visual.RenderRecursive(RenderContext ctx)    at
>   System.Windows.Media.Visual.UpdateChildren(RenderContext ctx,
>   ResourceHandle handle)    at
>   System.Windows.Media.Visual.RenderRecursive(RenderContext ctx)    at
>   System.Windows.Media.Visual.UpdateChildren(RenderContext ctx,
>   ResourceHandle handle)    at
>   System.Windows.Media.Visual.RenderRecursive(RenderContext ctx)    at
>   System.Windows.Media.Visual.Render(RenderContext ctx, UInt32
>   childIndex)    at
>   System.Windows.Media.CompositionTarget.Compile(Channel channel)    at
>   System.Windows.Media.CompositionTarget.System.Windows.Media.ICompositionTarget.Render(Boolean
>   inResize, Channel channel)    at
>   System.Windows.Media.MediaContext.Render(ICompositionTarget
>   resizedCompositionTarget)    at
>   System.Windows.Media.MediaContext.RenderMessageHandlerCore(Object
>   resizedCompositionTarget)    at
>   System.Windows.Media.MediaContext.RenderMessageHandler(Object
>   resizedCompositionTarget)    at
>   System.Windows.Threading.ExceptionWrapper.InternalRealCall(Delegate
>   callback, Object args, Int32 numArgs)    at
>   MS.Internal.Threading.ExceptionFilterHelper.TryCatchWhen(Object
>   source, Delegate method, Object args, Int32 numArgs, Delegate
>   catchHandler)    at
>   System.Windows.Threading.DispatcherOperation.InvokeImpl()    at
>   System.Threading.ExecutionContext.runTryCode(Object userData)    at
>   System.Runtime.CompilerServices.RuntimeHelpers.ExecuteCodeWithGuaranteedCleanup(TryCode
>   code, CleanupCode backoutCode, Object userData)    at
>   System.Threading.ExecutionContext.Run(ExecutionContext
>   executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state, Boolean
>   ignoreSyncCtx)    at
>   System.Threading.ExecutionContext.Run(ExecutionContext
>   executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state)    at
>   System.Windows.Threading.DispatcherOperation.Invoke()    at
>   System.Windows.Threading.Dispatcher.ProcessQueue()    at
>   System.Windows.Threading.Dispatcher.WndProcHook(IntPtr hwnd, Int32
>   msg, IntPtr wParam, IntPtr lParam, Boolean& handled)    at
>   MS.Win32.HwndWrapper.WndProc(IntPtr hwnd, Int32 msg, IntPtr wParam,
>   IntPtr lParam, Boolean& handled)    at
>   MS.Win32.HwndSubclass.DispatcherCallbackOperation(Object o)    at
>   System.Windows.Threading.ExceptionWrapper.InternalRealCall(Delegate
>   callback, Object args, Int32 numArgs)    at
>   MS.Internal.Threading.ExceptionFilterHelper.TryCatchWhen(Object
>   source, Delegate method, Object args, Int32 numArgs, Delegate
>   catchHandler)    at
>   System.Windows.Threading.Dispatcher.InvokeImpl(DispatcherPriority
>   priority, TimeSpan timeout, Delegate method, Object args, Int32
>   numArgs)    at MS.Win32.HwndSubclass.SubclassWndProc(IntPtr hwnd,
>   Int32 msg, IntPtr wParam, IntPtr lParam)    at
>   MS.Win32.UnsafeNativeMethods.DispatchMessage(MSG& msg)    at
>   System.Windows.Threading.Dispatcher.PushFrameImpl(DispatcherFrame
>   frame)    at System.Windows.Application.RunDispatcher(Object ignore)
>   at System.Windows.Application.RunInternal(Window window)    at
>   WPF_KSMMessenger.App.Main() in
>   C:\Users\Hossein\Desktop\WPF_KSMMessenger\WPF_KSMMessenger\obj\x86\Debug\App.g.cs:line
>   0    at System.AppDomain._nExecuteAssembly(RuntimeAssembly assembly,
>   String[] args)    at
>   Microsoft.VisualStudio.HostingProcess.HostProc.RunUsersAssembly()
>   at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.Run(ExecutionContext
>   executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state, Boolean
>   ignoreSyncCtx)    at
>   System.Threading.ExecutionContext.Run(ExecutionContext
>   executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state)    at
>   System.Threading.ThreadHelper.ThreadStart()

What should I do to solve this problem?

Thanks for your attention.

Comment: Did you check the file itself? is it correct?

Comment: What is the operating system? PNGs in WPF on XP can cause problems.

Comment: @ Mr. Disappointment: I am using Win7, not XP!

Comment: @ Thomas : Yes, the file is correct, and i can view it by Windows Image Viewer!

Comment: The other way to repro it is using a corrupted image. For example, saving a text file as an image will result in the same thing.

Comment: Just for Google: The German translation of this error is "**Es wurde keine passende Imagingkomponente zum Abschließen dieses Vorgangs gefunden.**".

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Your code works fine for me on a random image selected from Google images, so my guess is that the image you are downloading has an issue of some sort. You can try the following code in the handler right before Dispatcher.Invoke.

```
var encoder = new PngBitmapEncoder();
var image = new BitmapImage( new Uri( "MyImage.png", UriKind.Relative ) );
encoder.Frames.Add( BitmapFrame.Create( image ) );

using ( var stream = new FileStream( "MyImage2.png", FileMode.Create, FileAccess.Write ) )
{
    encoder.Save( stream );
}
```

Then use "MyImage2.png" instead. It is an attempt to have the encoder "fix" the image before loading it into the brush. To be honest, while this code works for me, I almost didn't post this because I have no idea if it will work for your situation, and I don't like posting code when I don't know the result. Definitely let me know if it helps.

Comment: Thanks you very much for your response. I've tested your code, it works fine in separate project, but, in my program, it still have that problem.

Comment: Can you post a link to one of the problem images? Or upload one to somewhere like imageshack?

Comment: I've use yahoo avatar image link. I am programming a chat client program. So, i must to download and process this images. I am using http://img.msg.yahoo.com/avatar.php?format=png&yids=<ID> link to download images.

Comment: I'm more interested in the actual image. Save one of the images that is giving you a problem to a file. Then upload that file at http://imageshack.us/. Select "Do not resize". Once you have the location, post it back here.

Comment: I found the problem, Yahoo can not response to some of IDs and program can't download valid *.png file ( for example : http://img.msg.yahoo.com/avatar.php?format=png&yids=arefpj ) , so cause to crash the program. Any way, so thanks for your response :)

Answer (score 20):

.png files with a zero file size will give this identical error.

Comment: This was my problem. I tried to read to same Stream twice without setting the position to 0 before reading the second time.

Comment: This also happens when you try to load a BMP file that you've just created from Windows Explorer.