# bitmapimage converting from byte array c#

Tags: c#, .net, bitmap

I am trying to convert byte array, which contains image description to bitmapimage

but I got an error: "Additional information: No imaging component suitable to complete this operation was found."

My code is:

```
public BitmapImage ImageData
    {
        get
        {
            BitmapImage btm;
            using (MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream(mSpaceObject.ImageData))
            {
                btm = new BitmapImage();
                btm.BeginInit();
                btm.StreamSource = ms;
                btm.CacheOption = BitmapCacheOption.OnLoad;
                btm.EndInit();
                btm.Freeze();
            }
            return btm;
        }
    }
```

Comment: Maybe [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14337071/convert-array-of-bytes-to-bitmapimage) question could prove useful

Comment: Add an error handler like this sample to see what's wrong with the image: [example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7292764/no-imaging-component-suitable-to-complete-this-operation-was-found-in-c-sharp)

Comment: The words "image description" do not mean much.  You need the bytes of an image, exactly the same format they have when stored in a file.  The error message means that it doesn't recognize the format.  So it probably just isn't valid data.  Save it to a file instead and use a hex viewer.  Post a screenshot of it.