# WPF suppress NotSupportedException : "pixel format not supported"

Tags: c#, wpf, image, taglib

NotSupportedException :  No information was found about this pixel format.

How can I suppress this exception 
, I tried the try {}catch (NotSupportedException) but it's not caught the application goes into break mode everytime.

I have read on some questions how to handle it(when one has an image file on disk) but my problem is that am generating these images using taglib dynamically so have the images on disk as a file.
         this.loadedImage.EndInit();`
            try
            {
                TagLib.File f = TagLib.File.Create(ImageUri);

```
            if (f.Tag.Pictures.Length > 0)
            {
                TagLib.IPicture pic = f.Tag.Pictures[0];
                MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream(pic.Data.Data);
                ms.Seek(0, SeekOrigin.Begin);                

                this.loadedImage.BeginInit();
                this.loadedImage.CacheOption = BitmapCacheOption.OnLoad;
                this.loadedImage.DownloadCompleted += this.OnDownloadCompleted;
                this.loadedImage.DownloadFailed += this.OnDownloadFailed;
                this.loadedImage.StreamSource = ms;
                this.loadedImage.EndInit();
            }
            else
            {
              // this.loadedImage = null; 
            }
        }
        catch (NotSupportedException el)
        {

          // MessageBox.Show(el.Message);
        }
```

`

Comment: Did you try handling the `DispatcherUnhandledException` event on the App?

Answer (score 1):

Apart from it is generally bad behaviour, to suppress exceptions without proper handling (at least logging it e.g.), you need  to change the Visual Studio Exception Settings (I asssume you are using VS) where you can tell it to stop breaking on that specific exception.

Visual Studio menu Debug -> Exceptions -> uncheck the specific exception in the Thrown column.

EDIT:
in newer VS versions, you can find this here:
Visual Studio menu Debug -> Windows -> Exception Settings -> uncheck the specific exception in the Thrown column.

EDIT 2:
You can also try unchecking that box when VS breaks on the exception:
[image: You can also try unchecking that box when VS breaks on the exception]

Either way, your application should catch the exception without crashing when you run it not from Visual Studio.

Comment: I edited my question, After checking the exception box the error is occurring on this line  this.loadedImage.EndInit();

Answer (score 0):

From this link ["No imaging component suitable to complete this operation was found."](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7292764/no-imaging-component-suitable-to-complete-this-operation-was-found)

There is this comment

.png files with a zero file size will give this identical error.

So actually before you pass the Memory stream data to the BitmapImage StreamSource you should check the byte [] array to a certain that the data is indeed valid or the byte array length is greater than zero.

E.g

```
  MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream(pic.Data.Data);
  if (pic.Data.Data.Length > 0)
 this.loadedImage.EndInit ();
```

This will skip images with zero length hence suppresing the exception.